# Adjust image attribute so I can change src

Tags: php, image, drupal, drupal-7

```
<img class="lazy" title="Windows 8" alt="Windows 8" src="http://b.a.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/category_pictures/Windows%20Media%20Player%20alt.png?itok=NXy-3w5_" href="lazy" data-original="http://b.a.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/category_pictures/Windows%20Media%20Player%20alt.png?itok=NXy-3w5_">
```

I would like to adjust the src so that it can display "/sites/all/themes/s5/images/blank.jpg" rather than the image url. Can you help me modify the below code I am using in Drupal 7's template.php to make this happen?

```
function s5_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
 if ($variables['style_name'] == 'thumbnail') {
     $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lazy';
     $variables['attributes']['data-original'][] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
}}
```

Thanks very much!!

Comment: total guess here, but try this:   
$variables['attributes']['data-original'][] = '/sites/all/themes/s5/images/blank.jpg';    

or try this:

$variables['attributes']['src'][] = '/sites/all/themes/s5/images/blank.jpg';

Comment: I've tried the "['src']" bit and it still shows the same output. Nothing changes.

Comment: What happens if you change the $variables['path']? Add the line: $variables['path'] = '/sites/all/themes/s5/images/blank.jpg'; just above the "if" statement.

Comment: we're getting somewhere!! that changed both the src and data-original to the custom path. I want to keep data-original and just modify the src, for lazyloading purposes.

Comment: see answer...setting the path after the "if" block should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a line to the bottom of the "if" block:

```
function s5_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
   if ($variables['style_name'] == 'thumbnail') {
       $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lazy';
       $variables['attributes']['data-original'][] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
       $variables['path'] = '/sites/all/themes/s5/images/blank.jpg';
   }
}
```

Comment: by adding that below the "if" statement, it affects all the images on the site, rather than just those that are thumbnails.

Comment: awwww..ok moved it to the bottom of the "if" block

Comment: Adding it to the bottom of the "if" block made the lazyloader work on the images, but in the html the src still shows the full file path, rather than the new custom one. Oh well, it still works the way i wanted it to. Thanks for your help, you are awesome!

Comment: hmmm...yeah you might have to dig deeper and find where the "img" tag is actually created from all the attributes and perhaps adjust it there. Glad I could help!